Two definitions of coNP
If $L\subseteq  \{0, 1\}^∗$ is a language, then we denote by $\overline{L}$ the complement of $L$. That is, $\overline{L} = \{0, 1\}^∗\setminus L.$
We make the following one definition of $\mathrm{coNP}$:
$$\mathrm{coNP} = \{L : \overline{L} ∈ \mathrm{NP}\}.$$
$\mathrm{coNP}$, ALTERNATIVE DEFINITION:
For every $L\subseteq  \{0, 1\}^∗$, we say that $L\in \mathrm{coNP}$ if there exists a polynomial $p \colon \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ and a
polynomial-time TM $M$ such that for every $x\in \{0, 1\}^∗$,
$$x\in L \iff \forall u \in \{0, 1\}^{p(|x|)}\: M(x, u) = 1.$$
I am not able to understand why and how both two definitions are equivalent; the book mentions these two but does not say anything about the equivalence.

Oh, I have checked the draft version, it's a erratum. You thus should find the published version on libgen, it have been revised partially, including the definition of coNP here. It's so sad that I have not yet found the official errata page.

We should prove that the former implies the latter definition and vice versa.
Let $\mathbf{coNP}=\{L:\overline{L}\in\mathbf{NP}\}$. For $L\in\mathbf{coNP}$, there exists a polynomial $p(n)$ and a polynomial-time TM $M$ such that for every $$x\in\overline{L}\iff\exists u\in\{0,1\}^{p(n)}\;M(x,u)=1$$ because $\overline{L}\in\mathbf{NP}$. Thus, $$x\in L\iff\forall u\in\{0,1\}^{p(n)}\;M(x,u)=0.$$ We additionally construct a polynomial-time deterministic TM $M'$ s.t. $M'(x)=1-M(x), \forall x\in\{0,1\}^*$. We finally have $L\in\mathbf{coNP}$, there exists a polynomial $p(n)$ and a polynomial-time TM $M'$ such that for every $$x\in L\iff\forall u\in\{0,1\}^{p(n)}\;M'(x,u)=1.$$
The other, i.e. the latter implies the former, is similar.

Would you edit your answer based on how the latter implies the former?

@Beduin It is similar, you should try to do it!
